# Standard process for creating complex xpath in protractor

Tags: xpath, protractor

I am looking for standard ways to arrive at complex xpath expressions in protractor.

For e.g. I have a complex xpath as follows:

```
(//*[contains(@class,'day')][normalize-space(text())='2'])[1]
```

Here I have to get first access to elements matching xpath

```
//*[contains(@class,'day')][normalize-space(text())='2']
```

and then pick the first from the matching ones. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor in its documentation clearly describes any process for creating xpaths:
http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide [section `Locator strategies`].

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't use XPath except as a last resort. I second [the recommendation by @Kacper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44899413/7709399) to read the style guide he posted.

However, if you're dead set on using XPath, (sometimes it is unavoidable), you can pick the first element that matches like so:

```
element.all(by.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'day')][normalize-space(text())='2']")).first();
```